# Rails: how can i customize the devise such that it produces user information after logging in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have devise for authentication system. When i use

> curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -H 'Accept:
>   application/json'   -X POST `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in`   -d
>   "{'user' : { 'email' : 'sample@example.com', 'password' :
>   'xxxxxxx'}}"

This gives me

> {"user":{"authentication_token":"yyyyyyyyyyyy","email":"sample@example.com"}}

but what i need is if login is valid i want some other data also along with it. For example it can be like country, name, language, etc. along with the present data. How can i do this?